# Can't find HDD drives after extend partition of Ubuntu on SSD

Tags: boot, grub2, hard-drive, ssd

I have a micro server, with one SSD and two HDDs. There are windows and Ubuntu on SSD. After the partition of Ubuntu is full, I tried to extend it. 
Using a live-usb Ubuntu system and GParted, I erase the Windows system and extend the partition of Ubuntu. After that, I manager to boot into Ubuntu but I can't find my two HDD drives.
I have tried `sudo fdisk -l` and `lsblk`, only /dev/sda is shown in the result. sda is my SSD driver.
Then I reboot and enter into grub command line. I tried `ls` there, the result is as follows:
[grub_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wd3Xa.jpg)
As you can see, there are three drivers: hd0,hd1 is my HDD, hd2 is my SSD.
But after I enter into the Ubuntu system, I still can't find hd0 and hd1.
Any thoughts about what's to do next?
 Thanks!

When the server started, I got this on the screen, I didn't pay attention to it before, but it said the two HDD drivers are unconfigured.
[HDD drivers status are unconfigured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdCYv.jpg)

I solved this problem, but I don't know how.

First, I got two blank disk so I can do whatever I want without worrying about the data.

Second, made raid 1 for these two disks.

Then, the disk can be seen in Ubuntu.

But, I don't need raid. So I delete raid configration and tried another solution.

During these procedure, I turn off SMART of these two disks on raid GUI interface. Then I got this problem: https://community.hpe.com/t5/ProLiant-Servers-Netservers/Microserver-Gen10-hangs-on-boot/td-p/6987843#.XSNDs-gzZPY

So, First, I initialize BIOS.

Second, reboot and enter the live-USB system

Third, "hot-plug" in my disks.
Then, after runing `lsblk`, Surprisingly, I found the disk.

Problem solved!

I don't know which step is critical, So I thought mybe it's reset BIOS works.

Comment: If you boot to the Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, can you see the two HDDs? Have you power-cycled the micro server and retried?

Comment: No, in the live USB I still can't see the two HDDs. I have powed off and pluge back in the server, the results are the same.

Comment: Are the HDD's enabled in the BIOS?

Comment: Check the BIOS with `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`. Then go to the manufacturer's web site and check for a newer one.

Comment: The HDD is enabled in the BIOS, and the firmware of BIOS is up-to-date.

Comment: Is there a utility to configure the Marvell disk controller? Have you tried to reseat the controller?

Comment: I reset the BIOS. There is a utility in efi shell to configure the marvel disk controller. I made a raid 1 array, then the disks can be seen in the Ubuntu system.

Comment: Thanks for the update!